# How to check if a certain key of each Json object has a particular value?

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, foreach

I am writing a unit test to check if searching by a parameter returns the correct data. E.g., searching ''employees'' table, column ''firstName'' by search parameter ''John'' should return only the employees with names ''John'', ''Johnny'', ''john'' etc. I get something like this in my JSon file, for each employee returned:

```
{
 "_index": "employees",
 "_id": "xyz",
 "_score": 4.306519,
 "_source": {
    "id": 51,
    "districtId": 71,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "divisionId": 20,
    "phone": "29437250"
}
```

I want to write a foreach loop to loop through all the employees and see if firstName of each corresponds to the search parameters, something like this:

```cs
foreach (var employee in employeesReturned)
{
    ...
    Assert.True(employee.Contains(searchParameter,
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

But how to write this properly? Should I somehow loop through the whole JSon file? Should I deserialize it? What would be an optimal thing to do?

Comment: For a true unit test, you should be able to test the result of the search before it gets serialised. That would also make your checks easier. If that's not possible, deserializing the response and checking that seems fine to me.

Comment: Could you please explain how from your unit-test you set up the employees table that is being searched?